# inside operator to include every element of systemverilog enum

Tags: system-verilog

Is there a way to use `inside` operator for every element of `enum`?
for e.g. I've the following `enum`:

```
typedef enum {ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD} Instr_t;
```

While writing constraints or checking if received `opcode` is any one of the valid Instructions, is there an easier way
I've tried the following:

```
if (opcode inside {Instr_t})
```

This fails and I need to use expanded `enum`:

```
if (opcode inside {ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD})
```

This is easy when `enum` is small but gets annoying with bigger `enum`, other way I could think is using `define`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for this constraint. The constraint solver is not allowed to assign a value to a random enum variable that is outside the set of declared enum labels.

The IEEE just approved a clarification to the LRM that will be release in the next update to the standard.

https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=4939

---

#### Update

If you want to create instruction subsets, you can put groups of enum labels into an array, and use the array with the inside operator

```
typedef enum {ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD,OR, AND, XOR} opcode_t;
const opcode_t arithmetic_ops[] = {ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD};
const opcode_t logical_ops[] = {OR, AND, XOR};


if (opcode inside {arithmetic_ops})
```

Comment: Thanks @dave_59, I should have explained bit more I guess. opcode is of type enum which includes all allowed instructions for e.g. logical operations so randomize() will go through OR, AND, XOR etc. as well (along arithmetic). And in case `inside` is used in if statement, if (opcode inside {enum}) can still be required even when opcode can only take values from enum to check for invalid case

Comment: You are not allowed to define another enum type with the same labels in the same scope. I'll update my answer with a suggested approach.

Comment: Thanks @dave_59 that looks much better approach, I will try it. I was not defining enum itself but the code inside `inside` block so basically `define ARITH ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD` and then use `if (opcode inside {``ARITH};` However your solution seems better coding and I don't need to rely on defines.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first declare a variable of that enum and use it with inside.

For example:

```
opcode_t op; 
if(opcode inside {op}) 
//continue
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to check a value against the entire enum space, you can do:

```
opcode_t op = opcode_t'(42);
if (op.name()=="") begin
  $display("Invalid opcode: %s (%d)", op.name(), op);
end
```